# Typesafe Activator が CoffeeScriptをコンパイルせず、 auto-reloading も動かなくなった

Tags: scala, playframework

Play Framework で Scala を使って Web アプリケーションを開発しています。

昨日までは順調に開発できていたのですが、 Activator (sbt) が CoffeeScript をコンパイルせず、また、 auto-reloading が機能しないようになってしまい困っています。

システム環境設定の "Java コントロールパネル" をいじったことが原因として思い当たるのですが、元の状態に戻しても治りませんでした。

`plugins.sbt` に CoffeeScript に関する記述はされています。

原因の検討がつく方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。
非常に情報量が少なくて申し訳ございません。
読んでいただいてありがとうございます。

環境は

- Mac OS X 10.10.1
- Activator 1.2.10
- Scala 2.11.2
- Java 1.6.0_65
- Play Framework 2.3.7

**追記...**

Activator で新しく作成したプロジェクトでも同じ症状が出てしまいます orz

Comment: playframeworkのversionはいくつでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージが表示されているのでしたら、それらの追記をお願いします。

Comment: エラーメッセージはありません。
activatorやsbtを用いたcompile時にcoffeescriptがスルーされてしまっています。coffeescriptのロケーションはassets/javascriptsになっています。

Comment: playframeworkのversionは2.3.7です

Comment: あと、問題の切り分けのために念のためですが、こういう場合activatorではなく、sbtを直で使ってみたほうがいいと思います

Answer (score 1):

情報少ないので、かなり推測になってしまいますが

- playは2.3.5以降で、そのあたりの仕組みが結構変わった(内部的に、run-supportというモジュールに分かれた)
- 2.3.5以降だと、Java6とJava7以上で処理を分けている
- 具体的にはこのファイルとか参照 https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.7/framework/src/run-support/src/main/scala/play/runsupport/PlayWatchService.scala

ので、とりあえず思いつくのは

- Javaのversionを変える(7か8にしてみる)
- playのversionを変える(play2.3.4以前と、2.3.5以降の両方を試す)

などでしょうか？